# Can't seem to compare the background-color of table data on click, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, css

Making a quick JQuery demo where clicking a table element changes it from black to white. I start them out checkered. However, they always turn black when I click them, and I cannot get them to turn back to white. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$('table tr td').click(function() {
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'black')
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    else
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `css()` method returns a RGB color (vendor-specific!). So, use the following code instead:

```
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') //rgb(0,0,0) = black
```

---

A *better*, easier-to-maintain method to change the appearance can be achieved by using the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method:

```
/* CSS code*/
.black {background-color: black;}
.white {background-color: white;}
/* JavaScript*/

$('table tr td').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("black white");
});
```

Comment: The format of the `background-color` and `color` is dependent on the browser version and not jQuery...

Comment: @Xander That's true, the `.css` method uses the `window.getComputedStyle` method (or `currentStyle` property for IE) to get the computed style.

Comment: I think the classes in toggleClass should be a single string.

Comment: @RichardD For a switch, true. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a job to jQuery's [**toggle**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('table tr td').toggle(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
}, function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra5vP/

Comment: @RichardD, I suppose. Your solution doesn't work if there's a third class setting the background-color. So there's always something: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra5vP/2/

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to use two classes and switch between them.

CSS

```
.black { background-color: black; }
.white { background-color: white; }
```

JavaScript

```
$('table tr td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('black white');
});
```

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Ra5vP/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `toggle` approach instead...

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css('background-color') and
>   .css('backgroundColor'). Different browsers may return CSS color
>   values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF,
>   #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

http://api.jquery.com/css/